# JSF - SessionExpirationPhaseListener on a JBoss Cluster

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss7.x, session-timeout, phaselistener

we are getting this exception:

> TimeoutException: JBAS010213: Cannot acquire lock default-host/...

We are using this PhaseListener in our web application to capture session timeout on ajax requests and redirect to index (we are suspecting this could be related, but we dont know):

```
public class SessionExpirationPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {

    return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;

}

@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
}

@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    if (httpRequest.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !httpRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
        String facesRequestHeader = httpRequest.getHeader("Faces-Request");
        boolean isAjaxRequest = facesRequestHeader != null && facesRequestHeader.equals("partial/ajax");
        // navigate to home page only for ajax requests
        if (isAjaxRequest) {
            ConfigurableNavigationHandler handler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            handler.performNavigation("home");
        }
    }
}
```

}

We are running over a JBoss cluster with 2 nodes (mod_cluster + apache) and have SSO enabled.
Do you guys know what could be wrong? Or at least point us to the right direction?

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: What version of jboss you are using? Do you have enabled sticky session mode?

Comment: Federico, we are using JBoss EAP 6.3 and sticky session mode enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here are to two nodes trying to get access to the same session, where one node is handling an incoming request, and the second node is performing a  session expiration.

Check cookies are being sent in your ajax call, a possible problem is the execution of phase listener in the node that not be owner of session.

**EDIT:**

Exist this bug maybe associated to this problem: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=993041

Comment: We removed the SessionExpirationPhaseListener, and still happening.

Comment: @Mateo please take a look in links that I have added to answer.

Comment: The first link appears to be really similar to our scenario, but i dont understand the second one.

Comment: Thanks @Federico, Reading this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/162109?start=0&tstart=0 , i realized that setting stickySessionsRemove to true in JBoss could be a possible solution. We are testing that on production right now.

Comment: Ok, the scenario we are dealing with is the next: The first login of the day gets like 5 minutes to complete, the rest of the day all ok. No logs, any idea?

Comment: We have an apache2 in front of the cluster, i checked the logs and at that time on error.log(apache):
[Thu Nov 06 08:34:29 2014] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
[Thu Nov 06 08:34:29 2014] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
[Thu Nov 06 08:34:29 2014] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: dialog to MY_IP:MY_PORT (MY_DOMAIN) failed
[Thu Nov 06 08:34:30 2014] [error] proxy: ajp: disabled connection for (MY_DOMAIN)
[Thu Nov 06 08:34:35 2014] [error] proxy: ajp: disabled connection for (MY_DOMAIN)

Comment: And on other_vhosts_access.log:
DISABLE-APP / HTTP/1.1" 200 205 "-" "ClusterListener/1.0

Comment: take a look in this issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODCLUSTER-425, maybe playing with max-connections on JBoss side helps

Comment: I think upgrading to EAP 6.4 would help you.